# Extending a function defined on an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-topology

This question appeared on an old qualifying exam:

> Let $X$ be any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ a function with the following property. For every $x\in X$ there is a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a smooth function $f_x\colon U_x \to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f = f_x$ on $X\cap U_x$. Show that there is an open set $U\in\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $X$ and a smooth function $g\colon U\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g|X = f$.

My initial reaction was that this statement is probably not true without any conditions on the subset $X$. However, I haven't been able to come up with a counterexample.

I know how to solve this problem for $X$ a closed subset. It seems to me that if we can prove $\{U_x\}_{x\in X}$ has a locally finite refinement, then we can take $U$ as the union of the refinement. Then we take a partition of unity and construct our function $g$ on that refinement by averaging all the $\{f_x\}$  for the refinement. I just don't know how to prove that there exists such a refinement (or even if one exists). Thanks.

Comment: I believe this question boils down to whether or not there exist subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are not paracompact. Apparently, a Hausdorff normal space is paracompact iff it admits partitions of unity subordinate to any open cover. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is completely normal, so every subspace is normal (in particular $X$ is normal), and being Hausdorff is hereditary, so every subspace is Hausdorff. I still haven't come up with a counterexample, though.

Comment: Every metric space is [paracompact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space).