# How to compete the proof of that for a map defined on an arbitrary subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ , we can extend $f$ to $C^r$ map on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, partitions-for-integration

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds*, by Munkres, at page 144, question 3, it is asked that

[image]

### Questions:

First of all, I was writing this question to ask whether my proof was correct or not, but down the road, I have realised that I have made a mistake, so now I have 2 questions:

1-) How to proceed from where I have left ?

2-) Is the part of the proof that I have already established correct ?

Note: I'm aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554884/extending-a-function-defined-on-an-arbitrary-subset-of-mathbbrn) question, but it has no answer.

**Edit:**

I just want to point out that, as you can guess, I'm studying real analysis.

---

### Unfinished Proof:

We first give a short lemma, and then prove the part **a-)**, and then part **b-)**

**Lemma:** If $\phi: U -> \mathbb{R} $, where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is continuous, s.t $S_\phi = Support \phi \subset U$, then $\phi(x) = 0$ for $x \in \partial S_\phi.$

Assume the opposite, i.e for some $x \in \partial S_\phi$, $\phi(x) = a \not = 0$, then, choose $0<\epsilon < a$, so let $0< \delta $ be arbitrary, and consider $y \in Ext(S_\phi)$ and $0 < |x-y| < \delta$. it is clear that 
$|\phi (x) - \phi (y) |= |a-0| > \epsilon$, hence a contradiction.QED

---

Now, lets prove the part **a-)**.

We first show the continuity of $h$, and then use induction on $r$.

Since $S_\phi$ is compact and $g$ is cont. on $S_\phi \subset U$, $g$ is bounded, but as we have shown in the lemma, $\phi (x) = 0$ for $x\in \partial S_\phi$, hence $\phi(x) g(x) = 0$ for $x\in \partial S_\phi$, hence $h$ is cont. on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, by induction hypothesis, let the result hold for some $n < r$, then

$D^{n+1} h(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      D^{n+1} (\phi * g) & x \in S_\phi \\
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases}
$

It is clear that $D^{n+1} h(x)$ is well-defined and exists everywhere. Moreover, $S_{D^{n+1} \phi * g} \subset S_\phi$, by the same method before, we can show that this function is again cont. hence $D^{n+1} h(x)$ is cont. . Hence by induction, we have desired result. QED

---

We now prove the part **b-)**.

Lets define 
$$\mathscr{A} = \{ U_x \subset \mathbb{R}^n | U_x \text{is an open nbd of } x\in S \}.$$

and $$A = \bigcup_{U_x \in \mathscr{A}} U_x.$$

It is clear that the sets $U_x$s form a cover for $S$. By a previous theorem on the book, we can find a partition of unit $\phi_i $on $A$ dominated by $\mathscr{A}$, s.t each $U_x$ intersect with finitely many $Support \phi_i = S_{\phi_i}$.

Hence, we define $h$ as

$ h(x) =  \begin{cases} 
       (\phi = \sum_i \phi_i)(x)  \cdot g(x) & x \in U_x \\
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases}
,$
where $g$ comes from the hypothesis that $f$ is differentiable at $x$.
By the construction of $\phi_i$s, (it is given in the theorem that is mentioned earlier), each $S_{\phi_i}$ is contained in one of $U_y$s, so for a fix $x \in S$, there is only finitely many $\phi_i (x) \not = 0$ , but if we can show that $Support of [\phi = \sum_i \phi_i)(x)]$ is contained in $U_x$, we could use the previous part to conclude the theorem, however, it does not have to be the case, so what can we do at this point ?